# How to keep a groupedby list sorted in Play Framework 2 templates

Tags: scala, sorting, playframework, playframework-2.2, templating

I've got a list of complex objects that I want to display, grouped by one of its attribute in a Play 2 template.

I managed to do it :

```
@measures.groupBy(_.question.category).map {
    case (category, items) => {
         // Category stuff
         @for(item <- items) {
             // List of items
         }
    }   
}
```

The problem is that the list was sorted in my Java controller, but the keyset of the map that I create is not sorted anymore (I would like to sort the key set using something like _.question.category.order).

Is there a way to have a sorted map on this attribute?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type is `measures`? Did you try to use a `LinkedHashSet`? This should keep the elements order in contrast to e.g. a `HashSet`.

Comment: measures is a List<Measure>. 

I use Java controllers. If I use a LinkedHashSet<Category, List<Mesures>), built in my controller, how can I iterate it?
Something like this?

    @measures.map {
        case (category, items) => {
             // Category stuff
             @for(item <- items) {
                 // List of items
             }
        }   
    }

Comment: Well, I just needed to change my point of view. Indeed, if I transform the list in map in my Java controller instead of doing a group by in the template, with a LinkedHashSet, the map is sorted.

Thanks mdell !